# While reading file, do i need to consider single encoding?

Tags: java, php, file, character-encoding

While reading file, do i need to consider single encoding ?

Here, Idea is simple, every file is supported only single encoding and it's design base on data available in file.

Different encoding like ..ASCII,UTF-8,UTF-16,ISO** etc.

Most of case, we considered and read file using only single encoding that UTF-8 but some complex chars are not supported for this encoding and in that case, we get junk or fault data char.

How do you read file ?

Comment: All Unicode characters are supported by UTF-8, but if the file uses a different encoding, you might of course get gibberish. You need to use the right encoding for each file. If you have control over how the files are written, you could use UTF-8 for everything.

Answer (score 0):

Your notion that a file have single encoding is not correct. See Character-set and Character-encoding are two different things. You can say that a file includes characters from a given character-set like ASCII(Printable characters, certain non-printable and control characters), but how those characters will be represented is determined by character-encoding. Thus a file containing ASCII character set may be encoded using ASCII,UTF-8,UTF-16 and so on. Just open a text file in notepad++ and go in Encoding menu, You'll see different menu-items available for viewing file in different encoding.

Hope it helps you.